# How do I make it so a String is turned into only words with spaces in between each?

Tags: java

I saw some other people who solved this problem before but there are still some hiccups when it comes to turning it into a String, such as

```
yes, it is true
```

turning into

```
yes  it is true
```

I tried to solve this problem to the best of my ability. Could someone help me with this because I am trying to count all the words and it eventually considers "" (the space between the spaces) as a word. Please help!

What I have so far:

```
public String cleanToken(String token2){
        token2 = token2.replaceAll("'s", " ");
        token2 = token2.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", " ");
        token2 = token2.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ");
        token2 = token2.replaceAll("   ", "");
        token2 = token2.replaceAll("  ", "");
        token2 = token2.replaceAll("\t", " ");
        token2 = token2.toLowerCase();
        return token2;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`\\s` will match any whitespace. So, something like

```
return token2
        .replaceAll("'s", " ")
        .replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ")
        .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
        .toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 StringUtils.normalizeSpace(s.replaceAll("\\W", ""));
```

Comment: That's from `Apache Commons` and it's `StringUtils.normalizeSpace`.  Not standard Java.

Comment: How do I import it?

Comment: To use:

    import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

Comment: It’s one of most common library used with java.

Comment: Im using BlueJ and it says "package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist"

Comment: You would have to download this jar.